# Repeat function continuously instead of invalidating

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift3, timer, func

How do I repeat this function continuously instead of invalidating it? I've marked out the else section at the bottom of the code and it currently just keeps displaying one title and not repeating the whole function.

```
func handleTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    if let currentPhase = self.phasesInProgress.last, let timerStart = timerStart {
        debugPrint("Current Phase: \(currentPhase.title)")

        let currentPhaseEndTime = TimeInterval(currentPhase.endTime)
        let elapsedTime = abs(timerStart.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        debugPrint("Elapsed Time: \(elapsedTime)")

        if elapsedTime > currentPhaseEndTime {
            debugPrint("Phase over current > \(currentPhaseEndTime), going to next.")
            self.phasesInProgress.removeLast()
            handleTimer(timer)
        } else {
            let phaseElapsed = elapsedTime - currentPhase.startTime
            let duration = currentPhase.endTime - currentPhase.startTime
            phaseTimeElapsedChanged(phaseElapsed, duration)
            phaseChanged(currentPhase.title)
        }

   // } else {
   //     self.timer?.invalidate()
   //     self.completion()
    }
```

Here is the timer section but it's not repeating the function.

```
 func start() {
    phasesInProgress = phases.reversed()
    timerStart = Date()
    let aTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak 
 self] (blockTimer) in
        self?.handleTimer(blockTimer)
    })
    timer = aTimer
    RunLoop.current.add(aTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    aTimer.fire()
}
```

Here's the section with the init

```
init(settings: MeditationSettings, phaseChangedBlock: @escaping StringClosure, timeChangedBlock: @escaping DoubleDoubleClosure, completion: @escaping  VoidClosure) {
    self.phaseChanged = phaseChangedBlock
    self.phaseTimeElapsedChanged = timeChangedBlock
    self.completion = completion

    addPhase(with: "Breathe In", duration: settings.breathIn)
    addPhase(with: "Hold", duration: settings.breathInHold)
    addPhase(with: "Breathe Out", duration: settings.breathOut)
    addPhase(with: "Hold", duration: settings.breathOutHold)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a `Timer` to repeat a function, so the first thing you need is creating a `Timer` property on your class

```
var myTimer: Timer!
```

After that it is necessary to instantiate the Timer and instruct it to execute the desired selector on the required time interval

```
myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, 
                                     target: self,
                                   selector: #selector(functionToExecute),
                                   userInfo: nil,
                                    repeats: true)
```

The function is therefore created as usually

```
func functionToExecute() {
    // perform your tasks here
}
```

And finally, when you're done with your code execution, you will just need to invalidate your Timer. As an example you can invalidate on the `viewDidDisappear()` method.

```
myTimer.invalidate()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with my timer section as it's not repeating the function.

Comment: I need it to auto repeat and not stop.

Comment: Yes, the function will repeat until you decide to `invalidate()` the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Start the timer in main thread like below :

```
func start() {
    phasesInProgress = phases.reversed()
    timerStart = Date()
    var aTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (blockTimer) in
        self?.handleTimer(blockTimer)
    })
    timer = aTimer
    RunLoop.current.add(aTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    aTimer.fire()
}
```

Comment: The 'DispatchQueue.main.async' isn't working outside the function and says 'Expected Declaration'.

Comment: Thanks, it says 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)' referring to 'RunLoop.current.add(aTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)' Not sure what this is about?

Comment: Sorry, Please check it now.

Comment: It's working thanks but it still isn't repeating the function.

Comment: If you are okay, can you please post some more code because its working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153983/discussion-between-vini-app-and-ned-bayne-powell).